# Lebesgue measure - $\alpha$ be defined for arbitrary subsets of $X$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Let $X$ be a set and let $\alpha$ be defined for arbitrary subsets of $X$ to $R$ and satisfy

$0\leq\alpha(E)\leq\alpha(E\cup F)\leq \alpha(E)+\alpha(F)$,

when $E$ and $F$ are subsets of $X$. Let $S$ be the collection of all subsets $E$ of $X$ such that

$\alpha(A)=\alpha(A\cap E)+\alpha(A\cap E^{c})$

for all $A\subset X$. If $S$ is non empty, it is an algebra and $\alpha$ is additive on $S$.

I'm just having trouble to show that the empty set belongs to $S$. 
I get the inequalite

$\alpha(A)\leq\alpha(A\cap \varnothing)+\alpha(A\cap \varnothing^{c})$

But I'm not getting the opposite inequality. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 'measurability' property you have, for $E \in S$,  $\alpha(A)=\alpha(A\cap E)+\alpha(A\cap E^{c})$ for all $A$.

Set $A = \emptyset$, and let $ E \in S$ (which is non-empty by assumption). Then the above gives $\alpha(\emptyset)=\alpha(\emptyset)+\alpha(\emptyset)$, which gives $\alpha(\emptyset)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

α(A∩∅^c)=α(A) so you get equality

Comment: But it is not hypothesis that $\alpha(\varnothing)=0$, it is necessary to show this and I don't know how.